# binomial coefficient divisibility properties

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm looking for a (possibly large) list of divisibility properties of binomial coefficients. Does anyone know a good reference?

For example, Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, Discrete Combinatorics, gives the "top 10 binomial coefficient identities", but where is an analogy for divisibility properties?